# Maple: click on button (maplet) from code or load text area automatically after restart

Tags: maple

I created "text area" maplets to define parameters. However, after restart, the parameters are not in the memory (clicking on them is enough to load them, but "execute all" do not load them). I created a button that fakes the modification of each text area, and thus load the parameters values into current workspace.

However... I still need to click once. Is there a way to load a bunch of parameters within "text area" after restart (the code should be shorter than ~3 lignes), or alternatively force the execution of a "button" **from the code** ?

A way of calling a long *hidden* procedure would do the job too (but it has to be included within the worksheet for compatibilities issues)...

Comment: Startup code could do the job, but I'll take other suggestions if there are.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Text Area or Math Container components for this. Just do the following:

1. Add the line defining the parameters in a Document Block or Execution Group, i.e. as regular worksheet code.
2. In the **View** menu, turn on **Markers**. A new vertical bar will appear next to the worksheet.
3. Right-click on the area in this marker bar adjacent to the Document Block or Execution Group that defines your parameter. In the generated menu select **Autoexecute** -> **Set**.
4. Now, that input line will be automatically executed whenever you restart the worksheet, without need for explicit execution.